# lambda search 'contains' not returning expected results

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, lambda

I have a lambda expression:

```
        var masterDocs = GetMasterDocs(new TNGService.TngServiceClient());
        var searchStr = txtDocSearch.Text;
        var filtered = masterDocs.Where(i => i.DisplayTitle.Contains(searchStr));
        lbxDocuments.DataSource = filtered;
        lbxDocuments.DataBind();
```

For some reason it is not returning expected results. For instance, there is a DisplayTitle that contains the word "Orifice" but when I run this expression, nothing is returned. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Contains` method is case sensitive. Can it be that your input and comparison differs in casing? To get around that, you can use `IndexOf` instead:

```
var filtered = masterDocs.Where(i => 
    i.DisplayTitle.IndexOf(
        searchStr, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```

Comment: aha, that was it lol. thanks. I just added in some .ToUpper() in there to even it out